# Antiderivative of $\sin(x-\pi/3)$

Tags: calculus, integration

I used $u$-substitution to break down the problem to be $-\cos(u)$ and then got my final answer to be $-\cos(x-\pi/3)$ (re-insertion for my $u$) and it is not completely correct. What am I missing or is there another step?

Comment: Why is it not completely correct?

Comment: Perhaps a constant of integration is needed.

Comment: Apparently it simplifies to -sin(x+pi/6)?

Comment: At least, this is what symbolab's antiderivative calculator states...

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is completely right up to integration constant.

$$I=\int \sin\left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\,dx$$

Substitution $u=x-\frac{\pi}{3}$, $du=dx$:

$$I=\int \sin\left(u\right)\,du=-\cos\left(u\right)+C=-\cos\left(x-\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

Since
$\cos(u)
=\sin(\pi/2-u)
$
and
$\cos(u)
=\cos(-u)
$,
$\cos(x-pi/3)
=\cos(\pi/3-x)
=\sin(\pi/2-(\pi/3-x))
=\sin(\pi/6+x)
$.